# View restriction not working

Tags: oracle, security

I need to create views depending on users on a oracle database
For that, using System I use the following querys:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  PROT_VIEW AS SELECT USER_ID, ORDER_DATE, ORDER_DESC 
FROM PROT 
WHERE USER_ID=USER;
```

the tables and the values of them are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE PROT(  
USER_ID VARCHAR2(10),  
ORDER_DATE DATE,  
ORDER_DESC VARCHAR2(60)); 

INSERT INTO PROT VALUES ('ADM',SYSDATE+4,'FOUR DAYS LATER');  
INSERT INTO PROT VALUES ('ADM',SYSDATE+5,'FIVE DAYS LATER'); 
INSERT INTO PROT VALUES ('STUD1',SYSDATE+6,'SIX DAYS LATER');  
INSERT INTO PROT VALUES ('STUD2',SYSDATE+7,'SEVEN DAYS LATER') ;
```

After this I have 3 different users (adm,stud1 and stud2) and when I log them on I should be getting 3 different results (one for each user) from each select I do (depending on the user logged).

The problem is, no matter what which user I have logged in (system,adm,stud1,stud2) I get empty tables.

I would like to know what i'm doing wrong and what can I do to solve this problem

Thank you in advance for anyone who's willing to help

update: i've been messing around and the problem is that i cant connect to those users. i've granted create session with system to those users and tried to connect to them but I'm stuck on system

Comment: I know it sounds silly, but have you confirmed with a `SELECT USER FROM dual` that the usernames are what you expect? I'm also curious if you get the same results doing `trim(upper(user_id))=trim(upper(user))`

Comment: Are you familiar with "schema" in Oracle, and ownership of tables? After you created the table, did you give SELECT privileges to the table (not just the view) to the users who will select from it?

Comment: yes I did. as I edited the problem is i'm always connected to system. I dont seem to be able to connect to the other users

Comment: What version of Oracle are you on? If it's 12, is it a multi-tenant configuration (container db and pluggable db)?

Comment: Im running oracle 11

Comment: Why can't you connect as those users? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Nice way to accomplish this task is to use `public synonym` in my opinion.

After creating your view (`prot_view`) on system schema, create a public synonym with the same name as view :

```
create or replace public synonym prot_view for prot_view;
```

and issue :

```
grant select on prot_view to public;
```

to be able to get desired result from every schema without prefixing with `system` schema name :

```
select * from prot_view;
```

Answer (score 0):

> "the problem is that i cant connect to those users"

`user` is a pseduo-column which returns the name of the account you're currently connected as. You're logged in as SYSTEM so that's the value of `user`, and that's why your view returns no rows. So, contrary to your question title, the view restriction *is* working.

Which means the the real question is, why can't you connect as those other users? You have SYSTEM so you have the necessary privileges to straighten out the accounts by changing the passwords to something you know or granting `create session`, or whatever.